# UILineBreakModeWordWrap does not wrap

Tags: ios

I have tried searching the web but still the problem is not solved.

I am showing a table inside an alerview and texts(for the field description) are not wrapped inside one cell.
here is the code:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell1";
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

// No cell available - create one.
if(cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}    
UILabel *scopeLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:999];
UILabel *descriptionLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1014];


NSDictionary *aScope = [_countryScopes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

scopeLabel.text = [aScope objectForKey:@"scope"];
scopeLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
scopeLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

descriptionLabel.text = [aScope objectForKey:@"description"];
descriptionLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;   
return cell;
```

And here is the screenshot:
[image]

And in my Storyboard the tableview: the description field length looks really short!
[image]

Comment: Looks ok...make sure the label is not larger than you think . Temporarily set it's background color to see if indeed the label is as long as you think.

Comment: I changed the label length really short and still I do not see the wrapping happens.

Comment: I don't think your labels are tall enough.  They will not automatically get taller.

Comment: thanks - looks like the problem is with the height of the label.